Posting Json body with headers and authentication using Visual Studio - Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) C#
I'm new with Json and C#. Trying build Windows Form in Visual Studio to post json data with headers and authentication using HttpClient and C# to external server (have no access). Here's the code I'm using:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

//Basic authentication
string username = "username";
string password = "password";
string auth = $"{username}:{password}";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(auth);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "API-Key");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var newPost = new CreateUser()
{
employeeNumber = tbEmployeeNumber.Text,
companyNumber = "123",
firstName = tbFirstName.Text,
lastName = tbLastName.Text,
active = true,
electronicAddresses = new electronicAddresses
{
addressType = "Main",
value = tbEmail.Text
}
};

var newPostJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPost);
var payLoad = new StringContent(newPostJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync("API-URL", payLoad).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

lblResult.Text = response;

When I'm running this, I'm always getting an empty result!
Status code from client.PostAsync("API-URL", payLoad).Result
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
But when I disabled authentication:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64);
Got StatusCode: 422, ReasonPhrase: 'Unprocessable Entity', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
When disabled API-Key:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "API-Key");
Got StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Access Denied', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
Testing with Postman working fine.
Posted via Postman
I don't know what am I doing wrong?
Any help/idea? Thanks in advance

Can you share how you send the request (header, body, authentication) via Postman? Besides, have you tried debugging and checking what is the status code from client.PostAsync("API-URL", payLoad).Result? To confirm whether the external API server processes your request correctly by knowing the status code (2XX - Success, 4XX - Client side error, 5XX - Server side error)

Hi, do you have access to the code on the backend side ? If yes did you check the result on the backend side ? Did the POST actually send the right data and everything ? And as suggested by @YongShun provide the Postman call

Hello, updated post with status and posted via Postman
